# How can I get full path as a argument of dir?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How can I get full path as a argument of dir?

```
FOR %%a IN (dir *.wav /s /b) DO (prop.bat %%a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do it

- You can use a `for` command to recursively iterate over the set of files and use the replaceable parameter to retrieve the information of the file
- You can use a `dir /s /b` command to retrieve the list of files and process this list with a `for /f` command

But and you are mixing both and this does not work. Also, to call a batch file from another batch file you need to use `call` command, else the execution will not return from called to caller.

To use a `for` recursive (`/r`) command

```dos
for /r %%a in (*.wav) do ( call prop.bat "%%a" )
```

To use a `for /f` to process the `dir` command

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b *.wav') do ( call prop.bat "%%a" )
```

In the first case, where the replaceable parameter (`%%a`) is a reference to a file, and as we are using a recursive search, it will contain the full path to the file being referenced. If the `for` is not recursive, `%%a` will give only the file name and extension, and the use of replaceable parameter modifiers is needed: `%%~fa` will return the full path to the file.

In the second case, the replaceable parameter iterates not over file references but over the output lines generated by the `dir` command. As `/s /b` switches are used, the lines already contain the full path to each file.